# Filter array to show rows with a specific value in a specific column

Tags: python, list

Let's say i have a multidimensional list l:

```
l = [['a', 1],['b', 2],['c', 3],['a', 4]]
```

and I want to return another list consisting only of the rows that has 'a' in their first list element:

```
m = [['a', 1],['a', 4]]
```

What's a good and efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Definitely a case for a list comprehension:

```
m = [row for row in l if 'a' in row[0]]
```

Here I'm taking your "having 'a' **in** the first element" literally, whence the use of the `in` operator.  If you want to restrict this to "having 'a' **as** the first element" (a very different thing from what you actually wrote!-), then

```
m = [row for row in l if 'a' == row[0]]
```

is more like it;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
m = [i for i in l if i[0] == 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
m = filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'a', l)
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
m = [x for x in l where x[0] == 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just:

```
m = [i for i in l if i[0] == 'a']
```

Or:

```
m = filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'a', l)
```

I doubt the difference between these will be significant performance-wise. Use whichever is most convenient. I don't like `lambda`s, but the `filter` can be replaced with `itertools.ifilter` for larger lists if that's a problem, but you can also change the list comprehension to a generator (change the `[]` to `()`) to achieve the same general result. Other than that, they're probably identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in l if i[0]=='a']
```

btw, take a look at Python's [list comprehension with conditions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).